# LinkError: WebAssembly.instantiate() function import requires a callable

Tags: javascript, c, asm.js, webassembly

I am practicing WebAssembly at https://github.com/mikerourke/learn-webassembly.

I tried to check the result of "without-glue.html", the last step of "chapter-05-create-load-module".

But it didn't run normally and I got the below error.

> LinkError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): Import #0 module="env"
> function="jsClearRect" error: function import requires a callable

I have checked the part of defining and loading the module in the html file, but I think there is no problem.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's complaining because it expects a function named `jsClearRect` in the import object `env`, but there isn't one.

There is a function named `_jsClearRect` though.